# Problem with Go Build: "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"

Tags: go, build, x509certificate

I'm getting this error message that I don't quite understand. I've tried Google and even ChatGPT, no luck whatsoever. I'm building this project using WSL and docker, run the Dockerfile using this simple .sh script:

```
docker build -t jobsupervisor .
docker run --rm -it -v "$(pwd)":/workspace jobsupervisor $@
```

Everything goes well, untill i get to the last line (cmd is where my main.go file is):

```
cd cmd && go build
```

when the "go build" is activated, I get these code lines:

`go: downloading google.golang.org/grpc v1.40.0`

`go: downloading github.com/google/uuid v1.3.0`

`go: downloading google.golang.org/protobuf v1.27.1`

`go: downloading gorm.io/gorm v1.21.15`

`go: downloading gorm.io/driver/sqlite v1.1.5`

And for each of these lines, I get this error message:
`../internal/jobsupervisor/jobsupervisor.go:22:2: github.com/google/uuid@v1.3.0: Get "https://proxy.golang.org/github.com/google/uuid/@v/v1.3.0.zip": x509: certificate signed by unknown authority`

And the build stops (for obvious reasons). What should I do?